# Cant change name of internal webcam via udev rules Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, udev

I need to change device name of internal camera

Rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTR{name}=="UVC Camera (046d:0825)", NAME="video2", SYMLINK="usb/video",  RUN+="/usr/bin/forudev"
```

I added *SYMLINK* and  *RUN* options for testing that this rule works. Symlink added and command executed, but device *video2* does not appear (device name still *video0* )

Running *man udev* i read

```
    NAME

     The name to use for a network interface. The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.
```

As i understand option "NAME" usefull ony for network devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try `dmesg | grep udev` ...

I am getting:

> [   20.553766] systemd-udevd[291]: NAME="video1" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-internal-webcam.rules:2

You will notice in the documentation that only network devices can be renamed... for the others, you only have the choice to create a symlink and use that to identify your device.